# How should a bicycle fit?

Tags: bike-fit, ergonomics, riding-position

[image]

**What are the characteristic features of a bicycle well-fitted to its rider?**

Are there a standard set of **"rider positions"** that we talk about in bicyle ergonomics?

What are the standard **tolerances and variances** of these heuristics in practice?

How do these features vary **by domain** (eg. road, mountain, grocery-getter)?

How do these features vary **by application** (eg. racing, touring, recreation, practical)?

---

Related (but not duplicate):

- [How to do a bike fit?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/how-to-do-a-bike-fit) 
  (This is similar but different because it's about *doing* a bike fit, versus what a good bike fit *is*.)
- [How should a bicycle helmet fit?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-should-a-bicycle-helmet-fit)
- [How is bicycle fit affected by switching from a riser bar to a flat bar?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/how-is-bicycle-fit-affected-by-switching-from-a-riser-bar-to-a-flat-bar)
- [Bike fit: Adjusting stem angle vs. height](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/61547/bike-fit-adjusting-stem-angle-vs-height)

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. People have written books about this subject and there a whole bike-fit industry in place to implement it, which is why you are getting 'to-broad' close votes.  Perhaps you can narrow your question so someone can give a reasonably short answer.

Comment: Please ask practical questions that help you in your cycling efforts.  This is really far too big.   For a start, read the "related" linked Q&A on the right side of the page.

Comment: @criggie et al. Is there scope for this to be a community wiki like the [terminology index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts) with some basic ideas about some of the major riding styles?

Comment: @Swifty No. Community wiki is for collaborative versions of posts that would, in principle, still be appropriate for one person to write. It's just a way to lower the bar for editing, not a way of bypassing site standards. Questions should almost never be community wiki, and "make it CW" is basically never the answer to "This question is inappropriate for Stack Exchange."

Comment: @Swifty probably not - there are whole books written on the field - its just too big to write up here.  If OP had more specific problems like "my pinkies go numb on drop bars" then that's much more bite-sized and can be answered in a couple paragraphs.  Good thinking though.

Answer (score 1):

To distil an entire field down to a short answer....

> The bicycle should be comfortable to the rider and for the rider's intended use.

How you go about getting to that state of comfort is a slightly longer-answer, and too big for this space.